# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy Public

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make a signedUrl PUT in my Javascript code, the URL was already signed by my Node.js API.

If I leave my Bucket Policy empty, I receive a Acess Denied message when performing the PUT request, but, when I set this policy:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1610714112327",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1610714107917",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucketname>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can successfully upload the file.

My question is: with this policy, anyone can PUT files into my bucket? Or just when they have a signed URL?

Comment: uploading content to a bucket required the access key apart from these settings.

Comment: @Kaushik I already have one, but is only in my back-end

The code is generating a signed URL, the problem is when I try to upload the file

Comment: and are you sharing the signed URL to user?

Comment: @Kaushik Yes, the idea is to upload large files directly from browser

Comment: Based on my understanding, If you're allowing from browser to upload and they are authorized user what's wrong in uploading the image, as you know the user.

Comment: @Kaushik Well, my question is: ANYONE can upload the files, or just people with the signed URL? Didn't got what you mean

Comment: I removed the bucket name from your policy and replaced it with a placeholder, the policy is dangerous as described in my answer.

Comment: You should remove this bucket policy, unless you genuinely want to allow any unauthenticated user to put objects to your bucket. The whole point of a pre-signed URL is that it intrinsically confers the permissions necessary to perform the action needed (upload in your case). You don't also need a bucket policy. The IAM credentials that were used to sign the pre-signed URL need to have the relevant permission (upload to the S3 bucket, in your case).

Comment: @Maurice -- the history is visible for anyone to see

Comment: Oh, that's okay actually, @Maurice this is just my devlopment bucket, and I already changed the policies

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer I know, I raised a custom flag for the moderators to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the Principal to `*` and shared the bucket name on stackoverflow - change that **immediately**!

Yes, anyone can upload objects to your bucket!

You don't necessarily need a bucket policy for presigned URLs, but the creating the URL needs all the permissions to do the Upload, i.e. at least `s3:PutObject`.
For more details, check out the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html).

Comment: My problem is, when I try to PUT the file using the presignedUrl WITHOUT the policy above, i receive the   <Code>AccessDenied</Code> error. The credentials that generate the URL have all the privileges to the bucket.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique We can address the problem, but that would be a separate question - this one is limited to your bucket policy. Mixing topics makes these questions harder to understand/reuse for future readers, so please create a new one :-) (If this answer solved your problem, feel free to accept it to let others now this question is solved)